# How to change the color of my nav bar when scrolling down on the web?

Tags: css-transitions

I need to know how I can change the color of the navigation bar when scrolling the web, Through a transition

I had the idea to animate my navigation bar once I scroll down the web, but I couldn't find the method in css3 to do it